# Vertical scrollbar is missing in mozilla firefox open child window

Tags: javascript, printing, scrollbar, childwindow

I have a sample [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5nof2cm7/4/) where I have a print preview page in a child window which is drawn as,

```
myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600','scrollbars=yes');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
```

But in Mozilla Firefox, the child window vertical scrollbar is missing. How can I fix this?
Also how can I repeat the table header row (ie, `Sl.No.` and `Value`) in each page of printed copy? I had tried using

```
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
        #headerRow {display:table-header-group;}
        tbody {display:table-row-group;} 
        .noprint {visibility: hidden;}
   </style>
```

But no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The scrollbar issue is solved by using,

   `myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes');`

Initially an extra `'` was present in between `height=600` and `scrollbars=yes`

2. The table header is solved by using bootstrap style for logo alignment and using `#headerRow {display:table-header-group;}` inside `media print`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/b6cxmqyj/2/)**

Anyways the table header is not repeating in chrome browser. Please suggest a fix.

Comment: Also use this code and I served    `var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

        this.myWindow = window.open('', '', strWindowFeatures);`